# SQL Server Collation problem (Msg 468, Level 16, State 9) in IF statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation, temporary-stored-procedures

My problem is occurring with a "simple-as-it-gets" IF statement, making the suggested fixes to many similar questions (e.g. [Cannot resolve the collation conflict in my query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144684/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-in-my-query)) seemingly useless.

The error message is :

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Procedure #XYZ, Line 11
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

It's known that the server collation is set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

This query demonstrates the problem :

```
-- this procedure (which gets put into tempdb) is called WITHOUT specifying @Choice  
CREATE PROCEDURE #XYZ 
(
    -- all other parameters removed (none of them have default values)
    @Choice AS NVARCHAR(1) = 'Y' 
)
AS  
BEGIN
    IF (@choice = 'Y')  -- error raised here 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @NULL_STATEMENT AS int -- only here because there's no "do nothing" statement
    END 
    RETURN
END
```

How can I fix this, given that altering the default collation of the server (and/or all of the tables) is NOT going to happen AND it is impractical to insert "COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT" in all queries, tables, etc. (for this solution see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4395/understanding-the-collate-databasedefault-clause-in-sql-server/ and [Cannot resolve the collation conflict between temp table and sys.objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028033/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-temp-table-and-sys-objects)).

Closely related links:

Documentation of the COLLATE clause: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-2017

A solution that I probably cannot use:  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2901/how-to-change-server-level-collation-for-a-sql-server-instance/

Comment: I mean, the simplest way would be to just change the `IF`: `IF ( @choice  = N'Y' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)`

Comment: That's a good solution for one line but I have many lines to change (I am porting known good working code from one machine to another).  But thanks to you and Sean Lange I see it's a  UTF-8 vs. ASCII problem and I suspect the root cause is that the servers were set up to use different encodings.

Comment: Nothing to do with UTF-8 vs. ASCII. The database you are in the context of when creating the temp procedure has collation  `Latin1_General_CI_AS` and the `tempdb` has collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. Neither of these are anything to do with UTF-8

Comment: And I've no idea why you think it is impractical to add `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` - SQL Server will tell you exactly where the problem is. So a bit tedious but easy to just add it where needed. Unless you have tens of thousands of lines of code you likely could have done it in the time taken to post this Q

Comment: Too bad @Sean Lange deleted his post as I was going to accept it.  He pointed out that you should make a similar change  (from 'Y' to N'Y') in the parameter line. That worked for me.

Comment: Are you sure when you made this change you receated the stored proc in the context of the same database as originally? You should still see this collation mismatch message for `nvarchar`.

Comment: @Martin Smith in my case UTF-8 vs ASCII is significant. I'm porting a known good application consisting of a Python 3.X front end (it passes UTF-8 values which is why nvarchars are being used) that calls SQL (via the pyODBC package) to a replacement SQL server.  No problems on source server since it's using UTF-8, obviously the new server was set up slightly differently (a hidden gotcha!).  Regardless, making the change to the parameter fixed the problem in a much easier (and cleaner) way than sprinkling "Collate Database_Default" throught the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've summarized the answer provided by @Sean Lange (a variation of @Lamak's comment) as it was was deleted before I could accept it.

The problem (for details see comments on original question) was that I hit a gotcha! while moving the working code to a new server.  The fix was to change the default parameter from ASCII (varchar) to nvarchar (UTF-8) form :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #XYZ 
(
    -- all other parameters removed (none of them have default values)
    @Choice AS NVARCHAR(1) = N'Y'  -- Note the leading N
)
AS 
....
```

The wierd thing is that after running that version  I was able to remove the leading N and the query worked without problems.

Answer (score 1):

(From the currently accepted answer):

> The fix was to change the default parameter from ASCII (varchar) to nvarchar (UTF-8) form

1. No, that did not fix it. That particular change had no effect since the value was converted to `NVARCHAR` when the T-SQL was parsed (due to the parameter/variable being `NVARCHAR`) and this error happens at compile time.
2. This issue has absolutely nothing to do with `NVARCHAR`, UTF-8, or even parameter default values.
3. UTF-8 is not being used here. SQL Server is only seeing UTF-16 as that is what Unicode strings are transferred in by the driver (i.e. the TDS / tabular data stream). And even when using a UTF-8 collation (new in SQL Server 2019), that encoding is only used with `VARCHAR` types as `NVARCHAR` is only ever UTF-16 (Little Endian).

The issue you ran into is one of several "odd" behaviors found in temporary stored procedures (both local and global). For temporary stored procs, parameters and variables will always have a collation matching the `tempdb` collation, while string literals will use the collation of the database where the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement was executed. These two collations do not change (for the main T-SQL context of the module) even if you use another database that has a different default collation other than `[tempdb]` and the database where the temporary proc was created (though dynamic SQL executed in a temporary stored procedure will use the *current* DB's collation! Fun, eh?).

Thus, as Martin Smith said in a comment on the question, you must have changed the "current" / "active" database when executing the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement after prefixing the parameter value with `N`.

The following example is a simplified version of the code shown in the question, but clearly shows that prefixing the string literals with `N` does not prevent the error.

Execute the following T-SQL in a database that has a different collation than `[tempdb]`:

```sql
-- The two returned collations need to be different, else no error with CREATE PROC:
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'tempdb', 'collation') AS [tempdb collation],
       DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'collation') AS [current DB collation];


SET NOEXEC ON;

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE #XYZ
(
  @Choice NVARCHAR(5) = N'Y'
)
AS  
BEGIN
  IF (@Choice = N'Y') PRINT 'yup';
END;
GO

SET NOEXEC OFF;

/*
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Procedure #XYZ, Line XXXXX [Batch Start Line YYYYY]
   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "{current_DB_collation}" and
   "{tempdb_collation}" in the equal to operation.
*/
```

(From the currently accepted answer):

> The weird thing is that after running that version I was able to remove the leading `N` and the query worked without problems.

Correct. That's due to the `N` prefix not actually having anything to do with the error or fixing it. You were simply in a DB that had a collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` which matched the `[tempdb]` collation.

---

<sub>I'm working on a blog post detailing several odd behaviors with temporary stored procedures, including this collation stuff. If / when I ever finish it, I will try to remember to update this answer with a link to it.</sub>